# Easy automated github server deployment to EC2 for small projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

not sure if this question is allowed here, but still trying.

I'm looking for a good webservice (maybe saas) to have github repositories easily linked to an ec2 instance and allowing different users with with access to a github repo automated deployment to the server.

What would be a good option for this. I'm mostly working on smaller website projects in most cases build with wordpress.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Do you want to automate deployment to AWS or something else? It's not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: yes, I want to automate deplyoment to AWS

Comment: There are number of services you can find useful for this https://aws.amazon.com/devops/ Also you can always use AWS CLI, API or 3rd party tools based on them to do whatever you want with AWS.